# Copy files to root Partition programatically

Tags: android, process, root

I am developing a root app for modifying build.prop programatically.
I copied build.prop from `/system/build.prop` to `/sdcard/`
but after modifying it I was unable to copy back to root partition

here is my code for copying build.prop from `/system/build.prop` to `/sdcard/`

```
protected void SUCommand()
{
    String sSUCommand = "cp /system/build.prop /sdcard/";
    final String[] sCommand = {"su","-c",sSUCommand};

    Thread thSUProcess = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sCommand);

            }
            catch(Exception e){}
        }

    };


    thSUProcess.start();

}
```

I changed `String sSUCommand = "cp /system/build.prop /sdcard/";` to `String sSUCommand = "cp /sdcard/build.prop /system/";` to copy it to system partition 
but didn't worked

I already rooted my phone and running lot of root apps successfully 
please tell me the right way to do it

Comment: I already rooted my phone and running lot of root apps successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to mount system partition as rw instead of rd so as to do it

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25250/how-to-mount-system-in-rw-mode-if-no-custom-recovery

Comment: error in mounting /system as rw --> C:\Users\Aditya\Desktop>adb 
# mount -ro remount,rw /system
mount -ro remount,rw /system
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory